# tool to start website designing

Tags: web-applications, ide, web

I am new to website programming(designing). Onething I have understood is writing html and css files by hand and then testing is not an efficient solution.. so I am in need of tools to start website designing atleast for the user interface part.

Like in netbeans/visual studio there is drag and drop option of various widgets.so I am need of any IDE for website development.Anybody please help..

I referred to other similar questions there was plenty and i was confused to use which one. please give me a good and most useful/widely used tool so that i can make queries if i get an doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe's Dreamweaver is extremely popular and doesn't muck up one's code too much.  I used it when I was starting out using HTML, and I'm sure it's advanced quite a bit since.  I now do the "by hand" thing -- it actually is efficient to do it that way, but there's a LOT more of a learning curve.

Cheers,

John